# Proof of concept for Magento multi-websites

Tags: magento

I am not sure if my question is suitable here. If not, forgive me.

Magento supports multi-websites on a single installation. Let's say that I'd like to make e-commerce websites for fashion industry merchants. I would install an e-commerce solution for each merchant. However, since Magento supports multiple websites on a single installation, can I just install a single Magento to support all the merchants? Each merchant has a domain and they don't share any information each other.

Or should I install a Magento for each merchant?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: Where are you hosting? The reason I ask is that due to networking restrictions, each SSL-protected domain will need to be on its own IP address. If you have root access to your server, this just means extra work for you. But, if you're on shared hosting this may not even be a possibility and could rule out multi-store Magento rather quickly.

Comment: Oh, this is a compelling reason not to. I didn't even think of it. Thanks.

Comment: So, other than that, conceptually it's ok to share a single Magento among many sites?

Comment: All your merchants will have to use 1 admin panel, and that may be a problem. Some actions (like reindexation) are resource-consuming and will affect other merchants, also there is a ton of actions that One merchants can perform, that will affect or even ruin other merchants content (like CMS pages, Categories, etc.). There is no "out-of-the-box" way to split Admin panel by websites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to support multiple Magento stores on one hosting account. If your hosting account allows parked domains, then it is possible to use one IP address to secure all the sites using a Unified Communications (UC) or multi-domain SSL certificate available from most vendors. Some of these certificates may support up to 100 unique domain names.

There are still other issues regarding performance that you should consider.

Comment: Is it possible to use different hosting accounts?

Comment: Possible, yes. But using Magento across multiple hosting accounts requires a level of sophistication well beyond the ordinary hosting account. You would have to be able to remotely access your database from one hosting account or else have three hosts with one being for your database. I'm sure larger Magento installations do this, but I have not had a need for anything this complex.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do this is doable. I was actually searching for a similar thing and found this resource:

[Magento KB: How Multiple Websites & Stores Work](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work/)

It is thus possible to have different web sites (with different domains) or a single web site with different store fronts.

I also found this explanation from the point of view of a hosting service on how to add two domains to a single Magento installation. Please note that this is specific for this service but you get the idea and the steps inside Magento should be roughly the same:

[How To Setup Multiple Magento Stores](http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/#adding-another-store-in-magento)